# Grammar rules for parsing optional keywords from list of words with LALR

Tags: python, parsing, lalr, lark-parser

I have strings with words like this:

- "ABC Some other stuff" (normaly there is a short letter combination at the beginning)
- "Some other stuff" (sometimes there is nothing interesting)
- "HFG 54 Some other stuff and even more" (sometimes there is an interesting number)
- "HFG 54 ZZ Some other stuff and even more" (sometimes there is ZZ after the number)
- "HFG-54 ZZ Some other stuff and even more" (soemtimes there is a dash)
- "ZT SOME OTHER STUFF" (The rest can be capitalized too)
- "(ZT) Some other stuff" (The part can be in brackets)
- "68 Some other stuff " (There can only be a number)
- "Some other stuff DFG" (can be at the end)

I made some rules to parse it and with larks Early-parser it works fine. Now i want to try it out with the Lalr-Parser but then the special words are not recognized.
I am interested in the capitalized letter combinations and the numbers. I have a list of the possible letter combinations. The numbers are always two digits. The rest of the string can be anything.

I am using [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark).
This is my parser:

```
from lark import Lark

tryoutabc = Lark(r"""
    start: mat_all_and_restl
    ?mat_all_and_restl: mat_all restl | restl | restl mat_br
    restl: REST*
    ?mat_all: mat_br| mat_num| num
    mat_num: mat_br ("-")? NUM
    ?num: NUM  ("ZZ")?
    NUM: /\d{2}/
    ?mat_br:  "("? MAT ")"?
    MAT:  "ABC" 
        | "HFG" 
        | "ZT" 
        | "DFG" 
    REST: /([\-])?[A-Za-zÜ]+([\/.][A-Za-zÜ]+)?/
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS
""", start='start', parser='lalr')   #remove "parser='lalr'" and the results are right
```

How do i have to change the rules to make it possible with the lalr-parser to parse this?

To try it out:

```
textl = ["ABC SOME OTHER STUFF", "Some other stuff", "HFG 54 Some other stuff and even     more",
         "HFG 54 ZZ Some other stuff and even more", "HFG-54 Some other stuff and even more", "ZT Some other stuff",
         "(ZT) Some other stuff", "Some other stuff DFG", "Some other stuff (DFG)", "68 Some other stuff "]
for text in textl:
    print(tryoutabc.parse(text).pretty())
```

I get

```
start
  restl
    ABC
    SOME
    OTHER
    STUFF
```

but i want

```
start
  ABC
  restl
    SOME
    OTHER
    STUFF
```

For `"HFG 54 Some other stuff and even more"` i get an error:

```
HFG 54 Some other stuff and even more
    ^

Expecting: {'REST'}`
```

but i want:

```
start
  mat_num
    HFG
    54
  restl
    Some
    other
    stuff
    and
    even
    more
```

In reality the strings are longer and look like this "Interesting stuff i already parsed ABC Some other stuff" and i already parsed the stuff at the beginning of the strings and it works pefect.

---

From the comments it appears that it is not possible to do that because i dont have a context free language here and apparently larl can only do cfg-languages. If somebody adds and answer where this both is explained quick i would be happy.

Comment: Terminals like `REST` are not what `lalr` is supposed to work with. Since a lot of stuff could match it is unclear what is supposed to match. It is better to use `earley`, or if the use case is this simple, maybe just a few regex.

Comment: @MegaIng so it is not possible? I already use earley and it works fine. The question was born out of interest.

Comment: No, not really. Lalr is designed for actual CFG languages, which yours isn't.

Comment: @MegaIng if you add an answer and can say why it is not a CFG language i could accept it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `REST` terminal. It can parse almost anything by design, meaning that

```
start
    mat_all_and_restl
      ABC
      restl
        SOME
        OTHER
        STUFF
```

and

```
start
    restl
      ABC
      SOME
      OTHER
      STUFF
```

Are both valid interpretations of the first example sentences (`ABC SOME OTHER STUFF`). This is something you can take  a look at if you pass `ambiguity='explicit'` to an earley parser.

This example works with `lalr`, since there isn't a problem if `lalr` just interprets everything as `REST`, but it does give you the wrong result.

The problematic example `"HFG 54 Some other stuff and even     more"` on the other hand doesn't work. It takes `HFG` as `REST`, and then tries to parse `54` which it can since it isn't `REST` and it doesn't expect a `NUM` right now.

---

If this is the full extended of you grammar, use `earley`, or for even more speed than lalr could provided, a (or multiple) regex might also do the job quite well.

(Note, I misspoke: this is potentially a CFG, just ambiguous. You could probably continue to hack on the grammar/the `REST` regex to make it work, but it won't be pretty.)